# How to use this Font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-awesome

How can use this font awesome icon in my project

[chalkboard-teacher](https://fontawesome.com/icons/chalkboard-teacher?style=solid)

I tried using `<i class="fa fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>`
but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

<i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>`

You are missing an `s` on the fa the latest font awesome project has updated these references

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the font-awesome cdn inside your head tag:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

After you've done that, you can use font-awesome icons inside your :

```
<i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>
```